# How to mock an interface in Guice module with ScalaMock?

Tags: scala, mocking, guice

How can I simply mock an interface needed for injection in Guice using ScalaMock?

Comment: For your tests, you shouldn't use Guice. So instead of injecting, you should write your unit tests by calling the constructor directly or making the complete injection by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Use a separate test module by binding mocked instances to class names and use that module to inject objects for your tests.

Test Module goes like this:

```
class TestModule extends AbstractModule {
  override def configure(): Unit = {
    val mockObject = mock[ClassName]
    bind(classOf[ClassName]).toInstance(mockObject)
  }
}
```

Spec goes like this:

```
class SomeSpec extends FlatSpec {
  val injector = Guice.createInjector(new TestModule)
  val mockObject = injector.getInstance(classOf[ClassName])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up using

```
import org.scalamock.MockFactoryBase
import org.scalatest.exceptions.TestFailedException

trait MyMockFactory extends MockFactoryBase {
  type ExpectationException = TestFailedException

  override protected def newExpectationException(message: String, methodName: Option[Symbol]): TestFailedException = ???
}
```

and in TestModule

```
class TestModule extends AbstractModule with MyMockFactory {
  override def configure(): Unit = {
    val mockObject = mock[ClassName]
    bind(classOf[ClassName]).toInstance(mockObject)
  }
}
```